# Unpack large zip file over itself

Tags: macos, archiving

I want to unpack 20Gb archive, but I don't have another 20-30Gb of HDD free space.
Is it possible to unpack this file over itself ?

So that zip file will be deleted after unpacking and I will have unpacked content.

Comment: There's also no guarantee you'd *just* need another 20gb of space, it really depends on compression ratios.

Comment: Of course. I understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `-m` (move) switch for unzip as there is for zip, but you can extract the files from the archive one by one and delete them immediately after extracting them.

I don't know much about OS X, but this works with Bash on Ubuntu:

```
IFS=$'\n'

for file in `zipinfo -Z1 ZIPFILE`; do
    unzip ZIPFILE $file && zip -d ZIPFILE $file
done

rm ZIPFILE

unset IFS
```

- `IFS=$'\n'` sets the internal field separator to newline, so filenames that contain spaces will get handled properly.
- `zipinfo -Z1 ZIPFILE` lists the contents of *ZIPFILE*, one by line.
- `` for file in `...`; do ??? done `` loops through the output of `...`, sets the variable *file* to one line the output of the command and executes `???`.
- `unzip ZIPFILE $file && zip -d ZIPFILE $file` extracts the file specified in *file* from the zipfile and deletes it from the archive (`zip -d`).

  Here, `&&` makes sure the second command gets executed only if the first terminated successfully.
- `rm ZIPFILE` removes the (empty) archive.
- `unset IFS` restores the default value of the internal file separator.

Comment: +1 for a useful answer, a good explanation and the use of `&&` in combination with the delete command.

Comment: I knew it. Solution exists! :)

Comment: if you have a good internet connection you can upload them or if you have DVD writer you can burned them to 3 DVDs

Comment: +1 for smart solution, as well as well explained and detailed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible. In your case you will need an extra storage media to send the extracted content; or move the zip to it and extract it to your hard drive.